# How to find first temporal occurrence of specific values for each pixel

Tags: python, netcdf, time-series, spatio-temporal-data, xarray

I have a NetCDF file for a given region in North America. It contains temperature data from 1959 to 2009.

1. I would like to extract the first day on which the temperature exceeds 273 K for each pixel.
2. This I will use to find the average day of >273 K for the region.
3. And obviously plot it in a time-series plot.

So far, I have found the days on which the temperature exceeds 273 K, but not the date where it first happens.

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('borealC_temp.nc')
print(ds)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 58, longitude: 114, time: 18385)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -166.5 -165.5 -164.5 ... -55.5 -54.5 -53.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 82.5 81.5 80.5 79.5 ... 28.5 27.5 26.5 25.5
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1959-09-01 1959-09-02 ... 2009-12-31
Data variables:
    crs        int32 ...
    temp       (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...


temp = ds.where(ds.temp > 273, drop = True)

test = #Here, I need to find the first day where temp > 273 occurs

annualdoy60 = test.sel(time = test.time.dt.year.isin(1960))
```

How do I found the first day on which >273 K occurs for each pixel?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for.

```
test = temp.isel(latitude=0,longitude=0, time=0)
annualdoy60 = test.sel(time = test.time.dt.year.isin(1960))
```

`drop=True` removes all the coordinates which match to `False` and thus indexing the first element of each coordinate will result in both, `temp` value and `time` it occurred first